# Is there a way to save information to a struct's pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am building a contact management application that requires info about the user and the user's spouse. I started with a struct where I initialized a name and a pointer to the spouse.

I have tried saving the input information to the pointer but I get the following error

```
GestionCarnet.c: In function ‘main’:
GestionCarnet.c:19:37: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct Contact’
     scanf("%s", (contact_00->Spouse)->Name);
```

And this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char Name[20];
    struct Contact *Spouse;
} Contact;

int main()
{
    Contact *contact_00;
    contact_00 = (Contact *)malloc(sizeof(Contact));

    printf("Add a contact: \n");
    printf("Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", (contact_00)->Name);
    printf("Spouse Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", (contact_00->Spouse)->Name);
    printf("================\n");
    free(contact_00);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to save info to a struct's pointer ? If , then how do I do it in my code? Thank you.

Comment: You have an anonymous struct declaration `typedef`d to `Contact`. Since the original `struct` is anonymous, there **is no** `struct Contact`, only `Contact`.

Comment: Also, you can't assign the spouse's name, because you only allocated one struct, not the spouse's struct.

Comment: Post input used.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be avoided by typing the struct name after **typedef struct**. So the struct definition becomes:

```
typedef struct Contact
{
    char Name[20];
    struct Contact *Spouse;
} Contact;
```

If you want to use `struct Contact *Spouse;` inside the struct then you will have to tell the compiler that it is going to be defined later, otherwise you will get an error.

The Spouse is a pointer here. It means that you will need to allocate memory for it whenever you want to use it. The following is the complete program that works fine after allocating memory for Spouse too:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Contact
{
    char Name[20];
    struct Contact *Spouse;
} Contact;

int main()
{
    Contact *contact_00;

    // Allocate both pointers
    contact_00 = (Contact *)malloc(sizeof(Contact));
    contact_00->Spouse = (Contact *)malloc(sizeof(Contact));

    printf("Add a contact: \n");
    printf("Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", (contact_00)->Name);
    printf("Spouse Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", (contact_00->Spouse)->Name);
    printf("================\n");

    // Testing:
    printf("Name: %s\n", (contact_00)->Name);
    printf("Spouse: %s\n", (contact_00->Spouse)->Name);

    // Free both pointers
    free(contact_00->Spouse);
    free(contact_00);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that error is that you are using the new type that you are defining when it was still undefined, a new type is defined after it was given a name.

- Is it possible to save info to a struct's pointer?

Yes it is, when you allocate memory for a struct you are allocating memory to all of its fields on the heap, if one of those fields is a pointer, you are allocating memory to a variable that holds a memory address. But you still haven't allocated memory for that address.
Also, don't forget that when you are freeing such struct you need to first of all free all the memory that its fields might point to, and then free the struct itself.

- If , then how do I do it in my code?

First of all we need to fix the struct and then allocate memory for the pointer, notice that I defined Contact as a pointer to a `struct contact_t`:

```
typedef struct contact_t{
    char Name[20];
    struct contact_t *Spouse;
} *Contact;
```

using the struct:

```
Contact contact_00 = malloc(sizeof(*contact_00));
//check malloc result
contact_00->Spouse = malloc(sizeof(*contact_00->Spouse));
//check malloc result

//your code 

free(contact_00->Spouse);
free(contact_00);
```

Note that casting `void*` (malloc return value) to other pointers is pointless.